# I am not getting a warning when I import a void pointer to a struct that has a pointer to a function in a shared object

Tags: c++, compilation, struct, shared-libraries, function-pointers

Yesterday I was doing some research on dynamic loading of shared objects and about getting pointers to functions.

I have been told many times that sharing pointers to functions through void pointers is forbidden by the ISO C++ standard and is still and issue to resolve.

After reading [Johan Petterson’s artitle “about the problem with dlsym”](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2004/12/problem-with-dlsym/) I understand better the reasons, and I also understand that being forbidden by the standard does not mean you absolutely must not use it. Otherwise, how do all C++ programmers work with functions from shared objects with correct ISO C++ code? Just guessing, I might be wrong, I am not very expert in C++.

While experimenting with my code, I found that by sharing a pointer to a struct which contains a reference to the function I want to invoke, my compiler will not complain. I use -Wall  and -pedantic while compiling.

My code looks as follows:

`myclass.hpp`

```
class myclass
{
    public:
    virtual void dosomething (void)=0;
}
```

`api.hpp`

```
#include <myclass.hpp>
struct API
{
    myclass* (* func)(void);
};
```

`so.hpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.cpp"
#include "api.hpp"

class childclass : public myclass
{
    void dosomething (void)
    {
        std::cout << "Did it.\n";
    }
}

/* function to return a new instance of childclass */

extern "C" myclass* make (void)
{
    return new childclass;
}

/* struct that contains a pointer to the function */

extern "C" API interface;
API interface
{
    make
};
```

`host.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "myclass.hpp"
#include "api.hpp"
int main (void)
{
    void * th = dlopen("./so.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    /* error checking was here */

    #ifndef usefunction

        API* api = static_cast<API*>( dlsym(th, "interface") );
        myclass * inst = api->make();
        inst->dosomething();

    #else

        myclass* (*func)(void) = reinterpret_cast<myclass* (*)(void)>( dlsym(th, "make") );
        /* will never get to this point */

    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Having already compiled `so.so`, I then compile my `host.cpp` file.

`g++ -ldl -Wall -pedantic  host.cpp -o host`
Compiles fine, program correcly prints `Did it.` when run.

`g++ -ldl -Wall -pedantic  host.cpp -o host -Dusefunction`
Complains

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
warning: ISO C++ forbids casting between pointer-to-function
and pointer-to-object [enabled by default]
```

I know it is just a warning, but why is not the warning print in the first case, when using the struct, if in the end I am indirectly being able to reference a pointer to a function that resides in a shared object?

Speaking of which, anybody knows a way to achieve all this in a totally correct ISO C++ manner? Does it even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your function pointer wrapped in a struct, then you are getting around the problem by adding an extra level of indirection.   Imagine if a function pointer took 10 bytes, but an object pointer took four bytes.  Your struct would be at least 10 bytes, and you would have a 4-byte pointer to that.  This is all perfectly fine.  When you access the struct to get to your function pointer, you pull out the full 10 bytes.  Nothing is lost.  However, if you were to cast the 10-byte function pointer to a 4-byte object pointer, you would necessarily lose 6 bytes of information.

This isn't an actual problem here, since platforms that support dlsym must have void pointers that are large enough to store the address of a function pointer, but the compiler is trying to prevent you from writing non-portable code.

Answer (score 1):

Totally standard conforming solution:

```
extern "C" typedef int (func_t)(char, double); // desired API function signature

int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(func_t *), "pointer cast impossible");

    void       *  p = dlsym(handle, "magic_function");
    char const * cp = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&p);

    func_t     * fp;

    std::copy(cp, cp + sizeof p, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&fp));

    return fp('a', 1.25);
}
```

One simpler, though more dubious way of writing this, uses a bit of type punning:

```
static_assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(func_t *), "pointer cast impossible");

void   * vp = dlsym(handle, "magic_function");
func_t * fp;

*reinterpret_cast<void **>(&fp) = vp;  // this is type-punning
```

Comment: Doesn't `static_assert` need to take an error message as well?

Comment: By existing the chance that the size of a void pointer might differ from the size to a pointer to the function that I want to point to... is it correct to assume that this method shares the same weaknesses of doing a direct cast (without a std::copy) despite of this being correct ISO C++?

Comment: @user1598585: `dlsym` is a platform-specific function provided by Posix, so on a Posix system this will work. The point is simply that the first piece of code is valid C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB could not they (my example and yours) fail for example if both binaries are compiled in different operating systems and/or under different architectures?

Comment: @user1598585: Sure. I wouldn't expect dynamic loading to work with object files compiled for a different architecture.

Comment: @KerrekSB as I am not so knowledgeable about this topic, I must ask: Is there any solution to that or do we have to live with it?

Comment: @user1598585: I don't understand. As far as I can see, there's no *problem*, is there?

Comment: @user1598585: there is no "solution" to the fact that x86 code can't get a function pointer to a function in an ARM executable. You can't call an ARM function from x86 code, and you can't even load an ARM dll on an x86 system in the first place, so you wouldn't have a handle to pass to `dlsym`. Binaries compiled for incompatible targets can't inter-operate, that's given, so `dlsym` doesn't have to support inter-operation.

Comment: @KerrekSB not quite a problem but might be an inconvenience.

Comment: @user1598585: It's the same "inconvenience" that you can't put a Gameboy cartridge in your DVD player and watch a walkthrough of the game -- nobody ever claimed that such interoperability should exist in the first place!

Comment: @KerrekSB that is what I wanted to know, thanks for the reply. I started this “research” because of what to said yesterday to my other question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, g++ *doesn't* treat linkage as part of the type.  You're `so.hpp`
shouldn't compile, because it attemps to initialize a `myclass* (*)()`
(a pointer to an `extern "C"` function) with `make`, which is an `extern
"C"` function.  This is illegal, and requires a compiler error, but g++
accepts it without even a warning.

Beyond that, why should `host.cpp` generate a warning if `usefunction`
isn't defined.  In the DLL, `interface` is an instance of a data type
which *contains* a pointer to a function.  You use `dlsym` to get the
address of this variable (not a function), which you cast to a data
type.  At no time to you convert a pointer to data to a pointer to a
function; you dereference a pointer to a data object which contains a
pointer to a function, which is fine.

As for the version with the `reinterpret_cast`, the warning is
justified: `dlsym` returns a pointer to the function (and not to a
variable), but it returns it as a `void*`.  The standard (at least
through C++03) says that this conversion is illegal, and I've used
compilers where it could not be made to work, because pointers to
functions were bigger than pointers to data.  As a restriction in what
it allows in C, Unix (Posix) requires pointers to functions and pointers
to data to have the same size and representation, and the Posix standard
says to convert the return value of `dlsym` as follows:

```
myclass* (*func)();
*reinterpret_cast<void**>( &func ) = dlsym( th, "make" );
```

If a `myclass* (*)()` and a `void*` actually do have the same size and
representation, this is legal, and will work (and shouldn't trigger any
warning).

Comment: Not disputing what Posix says, but isn't that code a violation of strict aliasing? If so, does Posix in effect introduce a requirement on the implementation that `void*` and function pointer types are valid for aliasing, everywhere, just in order to support this idiom? And if it doesn't introduce that requirement everywhere, how far can I stray from this formula before it's a strict aliasing violation again? Can I use a different variable name, a C-style cast instead of `reinterpret_cast`, can the call to `dlsym` be in a different statement/function/TU from the cast, etc?

Comment: @SteveJessop That's an interesting question, and I don't know the answer.  You're clearly accessing a variable through an lvalue different than its actual type, which is not a character type.  Since it's what Posix recommends, I can't imagine a compiler not making it work when everything is up front and in the same function.  On the other hand, if you have a function which takes both a `void** pv` and a `myclass* (**ppf)()`, calls `*pv = dlsym(...);` and then tries to call the function using `myclass *pc = (**ppf)();`, I can imagine it failing; the compiler can assume no alias, and rearrange.

Comment: Why is a pointer from an `extern "C"` struct member to an `extern "C"` function illegal? that’s it? I got it right?

Comment: OK, bonus question: Does there exist a function pointer type that's big enough to hold any function pointer? Like `void(*)()`?

Comment: @user1598585 The `struct` in question is _not_ `extern "C"`.  The pointer type it contains is declared in `api.hpp`, where there's not an `extern "C"` in site.  (In practice, `extern "C" on a data definition is without any effect.)

Comment: @Kerrek: yes, all pointer-to-function types have that property. 5.2.10/6, "converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value". As long as you define "big" in terms of the range of values representable, I don't think the standard says anything about `sizeof` different function pointer types.

Comment: @KerrekSB The standard guarantees that you can convert a function
pointer of one type to one of any other type and back, which more or
less means that all function pointers have the same size.  (This does
_not_ include pointer to member function, which is something else
entirely.)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks. Then it looks like `void(*)()` would have been a much better return type for `dlsym`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: but `dlsym` can return pointers to symbols other than functions, so you'd have the same problem in reverse. From the Posix `dlsym` rationale, "a future version may either add a new function to return function pointers, or the current interface may be deprecated in favor of two new functions: one that returns data pointers and the other that returns function pointers."

Answer (score 1):

The warning from gcc is because gcc doesn't know whether you are willing to assume Posix or not. So it assumes not and (as required by the C++ standard) it diagnoses the ill-formed program.

However, you're using `dlsym` and expecting it to do what Posix `dlsym` does, so you're willing to rely on Posix. Then you can do a C-style cast from `void*` to your function pointer type, and gcc guarantees that this is OK even though C++ doesn't. Any non-Posix system that imitates `dlsym` would have to guarantee something similar, since otherwise it's nonsense to return a function pointer in a `void*`.

Since you know what you're doing, you can then silence any warnings from gcc.

The reason that your code with the `API` structure doesn't give any warnings is that `void*` can be `static_cast` to any pointer-to-object. I think you violate strict aliasing when you access the data member, because you refer to the memory via an lvalue of type `API` and an lvalue of type pointer-to-function, when the actual object at that location is a `void*`. But because the layout of your struct is the same as the layout of a `void*` and a pointer-to-function on your implementation, it has worked anyway. In theory, even with the same layouts it could break because of the strict aliasing violation (more likely the more optimization you use).

The safe way to avoid strict aliasing violations is `std::memcpy(&fp, &p, sizeof p)`: the same as Kerrek's `std::copy`, but with fewer `reinterpret_casts` cluttering the place up because `memcpy` takes `void*` whereas `std::copy` requires a complete type. As well as avoiding a strict aliasing violation, this conveniently also avoids any diagnostic. You aren't casting between function and object pointers any more: you're directly copying the object representation of one into the other. Provided that the object representation of `void*` is guaranteed to be the same as pointer-to-function (which is the case in Posix), this will work.

Comment: `void*` *is* a complete type, non?

Comment: @Kerrek: yes, but `void` isn't. `std::copy` requires that *the things it's copying* have a complete type. It also requires that the iterator type is complete, of course, but that's not what I was driving at.

Comment: "you can do a C-style cast from `void* to your function pointer type": no you cannot.  It's not legal in C, nor in C++03.  (C++11 supports it conditionally.)  And Posix doesn't require it; in their example of `dlsym`, they use `*(void**)(&pf) = dlsym(...)` for the conversion, precisely because simply converting the return value would not be legal.

Comment: @James: I meant, you can in gcc. But you're right, it's not Posix that guarantees the result is correct, it's the Posix guarantees about representation of data/function pointers *together with* gcc's extension to actually do that cast by reinterpreting the object representation (whilst warning about it for conformance). Does Posix actively dis-recommend my preferred `memcpy`?

Comment: @SteveJessop As far as I know, they don't mention it.  Strictly speaking, it's probably the safest, and if for some reason the conversion wasn't taking place in a very restricted context, where the compiler could see all of the parts of it, it would be the solution I'd adopt.  (For g++, you could also use a `union` with a `void*` and the function pointer.  G++ guarantees that this would work.  But again, only in the context where it sees the `union` at both the read and the write sites.)